# Laravel 5.8 Multiple image upload

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am new to developing websites and I am really eager to learn! I am having trouble figuring out how to upload multiple images. I am building a recipe application and I currently have a working file upload in my RecipeController, however, I would like to adjust that so that I can upload multiple. Could someone point me in the right direction?

RecipeController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {        
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'ingredients' => 'required',
            'directions' => 'required',
            'recipeImage' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
        ]);

        // Handle File Upload 
            if($request->hasfile('recipeImage')){
                // Get filename with extension
                $fileameWithExt = $request->file('recipeImage')->getClientOriginalName();
                // Get just filename
                $filename = pathinfo($fileameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                // Get just extension
                $extension = $request->file('recipeImage')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                // Filename to store
                $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
                // Upload Image
                $path = $request->file('recipeImage')->storeAs('public/recipe_images', $fileNameToStore);
            } else {
                $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
            }

            $recipe = new Recipe;
            $recipe->author = auth()->user()->username;
            $recipe->title = $request->input('title');
            $recipe->description = $request->input('description');
            $recipe->ingredients = $request->input('ingredients');
            $recipe->directions = $request->input('directions');
            $recipe->recipeImage = $fileNameToStore;
            $recipe->prepTime = $request->input('prepTime');
            $recipe->cookTime = $request->input('cookTime');
            $recipe->servings = $request->input('servings');
            $recipe->calories = $request->input('calories');
            $recipe->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

            $recipe->save();

            $recipe->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

            return redirect('/recipes')->with('success', 'Recipe Posted!');
```

I am trying to make the column "recipeImage" in my database table "recipes" to hold multiple images if a user chooses to upload. I have found a few things online but the all involve revamping my whole code to make the DB insert using jQuery. Is there a way to do it right here in my controller? Or do I have to use something like jQuery to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: In your code , you are doing for single image upload and want for multiple??

Comment: Yes! right now it is only uploading a single image. I want to be able to upload multiple images to one recipe.

Comment: are you handling multiple file upload or single file upload

Answer (score 3):

**Best approach** is to create different table of `recipe_images` for multiple images uploading and make `foreign key` as `recipe_id` in the `recipe_images` table with the relationship of **Recipe has many images.**

Like:

**recipe** table:

```
id | author | title | description | etc...
```

**recipe_images** table:

```
id | recipe_id | image | timestamps
```

In your **Recipe Model**:

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RecipeImages', 'recipe_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

In your **RecipeImages Model**:

```
class RecipeImages extends Model
{
    public function recipe()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe');
    }
}
```

And then in your **blade** file:

```
<input type="file" name="recipeImage[]" multiple>
```

And **Controller** to store multiple images in storage as well as db:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{        
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'ingredients' => 'required',
        'directions' => 'required',
        'recipeImage' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ]);

    $recipe = new Recipe;
    $recipe->author = auth()->user()->username;
    $recipe->title = $request->input('title');
    $recipe->description = $request->input('description');
    $recipe->ingredients = $request->input('ingredients');
    $recipe->directions = $request->input('directions');
    $recipe->prepTime = $request->input('prepTime');
    $recipe->cookTime = $request->input('cookTime');
    $recipe->servings = $request->input('servings');
    $recipe->calories = $request->input('calories');
    $recipe->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $recipe->save();

    // Handle multiple file upload
    $images = $request->file('recipeImage');
    foreach($images as $key => $image) {
        if ($request->hasFile('recipeImage')[$key] && $request->file('recipeImage')[$key]->isValid()) {
            // store image to directory.
            $path = $request->recipeImage[$key]->store('public/recipe_images/');
            $path = basename($path);

            // store image to database.
            $r_image = new RecipeImages();
            $r_image->recipe_id = $recipe->id;
            $r_image->image = $path;
            $r_image->save();
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('errors', 'Invalid Image file found!');
        }
    }

    $recipe->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

    return redirect('/recipes')->with('success', 'Recipe Posted!');
}
```

**Form in create.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('RecipesController@store') }}" id="submitRecipeForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

        <section class="createRecipe">

            <div class="createRecipeLeftBody">
                <div class="photoUploadInput">
                    <label for="imageUpload">
                        <input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="recipeImage[]" multiple>
                    </label>
                    <span>Add a photo of your recipe!</span>
                </div>


            <div class="container">
                <ul class="createRecipeInfo">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">

                                <li>
                                    <label for="prep" class="prep">Prep Time</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="prep" id="prep" name="prepTime">
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="cookTime">Cook Time</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="cookTime" name="cookTime">
                                </li>
                            </div><!-- col-lg-6 --> 

                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <li>
                                    <label for="servings">Serves: </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="servings" name="servings">
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="calories">Calories/serving</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="calories" name="calories">
                                </li>
                            </div>

                    </div><!-- row -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!-- container -->


            <div class="createRecipeBody"> 

                    <h2>Create Recipe <hr></h2>
                <fieldset>
                    <small class="errorMessage">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</small>
                    <label for="title">Give your creation a title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <small class="errorMessage"></small>
                        <label for="tags">Tags</label>
                        <select name="tags[]" id="tagsList" class="select2-multi" multiple="multiple">
                            @foreach($tags as $tag)
                                 <option value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <small class="errorMessage">{{ $errors->first('description') }}</small>
                    <label for="description">Describe your creation</label>
                    <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <small class="errorMessage">{{ $errors->first('ingredients') }}</small>
                    <label for="ingredientList">List the ingredients</label>
                    <textarea name="ingredients" id="ingredientList" placeholder="Please list each ingredient on a seperate line"></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <small class="errorMessage">{{ $errors->first('directions') }}</small>
                        <label for="ingredientList">Directions</label>
                        <textarea name="directions" id="directions" placeholder="Please list each step on a seperate line"></textarea>
                </fieldset>


                <div class="terms">
                    <label class="authenticationCheck">
                        <input class="termsOfService" type="checkbox">
                        <span>
                            Public Recipe
                        </span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="authenticationCheck">
                        <input class="termsOfService" type="checkbox">
                        <span>Private Recipe</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="submitRecipe" type="submit">Share your creation</button>
            </div>
        </section>
</form>
```

Comment: I can't get it to post the recipe. I hit submit and nothing happens. It seems as though it can't process the logic in the controller due to the order. My previous code works, but with the new table and model, it doesn't upload. Thoughts?

Comment: It's been added to your answer at the bottom

Comment: Please `dd($request->all());` in top of the store function to check that all the request comes from the form or not?